# How to switch window with swiss german keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I got used to switching between open windows in an application on my other mac (US keyboard: `command + tilde`.

This doesn't really work on swiss german keyboards, since the tilde is generated with: `alt + n`. Pressing command + alt + n behaves the same as `command + n`, that is, the applications tend to open new windows instead of cycling existing ones.

Any tips?

Comment: I have tried (command + shift + ^) and (command + <) on my Swiss keyboard, but .... no luck. Does anyone have other options to suggest? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And you can edit this in your general settings > keyboard > shortcut to suit your needs.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Feel free to edit this into the flow of the top voted answer or flesh out your answer since the two together might be the best answer.

Comment: @bmike, in fact, I'm just going to accept this answer, as it includes information on how to find out the correct answer for any keyboard ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Never mind, I just figured it out by myself:

It turns out, on swiss german keyboards, the shortcut for cycling through windows is not `command + tilde` but instead `command + backtick`. The backtick is on the same key as caret, which is the first key to the left of the backspace key. Therefore, I need to press:

```
command + shift + ^
```

Comment: This does not work on my German keyboard.

Comment: @gentmatt: For the german keyboard, it may work with `command + <` and `command + >` resp. Check it out [here](http://superuser.com/questions/299241/in-mac-os-what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-instances-of-the-same)

Comment: Just for the record, on the German keyboard it's `command + shift + \` `. The apostrophe is on the same place on the German keyboard as circumflex on the Swiss one, i.e., to the left of backspace.